# Spark RDD aggregate /fold operation business scenario

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate, rdd

*[Edit] Actually, my question is about the business scenario/requirement for Spark RDD aggregate operation especially with zeroValue and RDD partition, but not for how it work in Spark. Sorry for the confusion.*

I was learning all kinds of Spark RDD calculation. When looking into Spark RDD aggregate /fold related, I can not think about the business scenario of aggregate/fold.

For example, I am going to calculate sum of value in a RDD by fold.

```
val myrdd1 = sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 2)
myrdd1.fold(1)((x,y) => x + y)
```

it returns 58.

if we change partition number from 2 to 4, it returns 60. But I expect 55.

I understood what spark did if did not give the partition number when making the myrdd1. it will take the default partition number which is not known. The return value will be "unstable".

So I do not know why Spark has this kind of logic. Is there real business scenario has this kind of requirement?

Answer (score 0):

`fold` aggregates the data per partition, starting with `zero value` from the first parenthesis. Partitions aggregation results are at the end combined with zero value.

Thus, for 2 partitions you correctly received 58:
(1+1+2+3+4+5)+(1+6+7+8+9+10)+1

Same, for 4 partitions a correct result was 60:
(1+1+2+3)+(1+4+5+6)+(1+7+8)+(1+9+10)+1

For real world scenarios, such kind of computations (divide-and-conquer like) may be useful everywhere you have a commutative logic, i.e. when the order of operations execution doesn't matter, like in mathematical addition. With that Spark will only move across the network partial results of aggregations instead of, for instance, shuffle whole blocks.

Your expectation about "receiving 55" if instead of `fold` you'd use `treeReduce`:

```
"treeReduce" should "compute sum of numbers" in {
  val numbersRdd = sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 20, 10)
  val sumComputation = (v1: Int, v2: Int) => v1 + v2

  val treeSum = numbersRdd.treeReduce(sumComputation, 2)

  treeSum shouldEqual(210)
  val reducedSum = numbersRdd.reduce(sumComputation)
  reducedSum shouldEqual(treeSum)
```

}

Some time ago I wrote a small post about tree aggregations in RDD: http://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/tree-aggregations-spark/read

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not clear with your real world scenarios. Seems your example is saying that the aggregate is only for spark internal execution(shuffle) calculation.  I have another example, I have 10 numbers in a RDD, the RDD has two partitions. I am going to get the maximum and second maximun within the 10 number. The numbers are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.  The calculation return might be 7 and 10, if 1,2,3,4,7 are on one partition and 5,6,8,9,10 are one another partition. But the correct answer must be 9 and 10.

Comment: For your example with 2 max numbers, if instead of returning 1 number/partition you return 2 numbers, you'll get correct result. fold can be used if, from your partial results, you can compute the final one, i.e. you have a subset of data on each partition, you make your partial results and finally you combine them to the final one.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I can change the second param of aggregate to get correct answer. I am just confused what is real meaning of these calculation, especially the partition num impact the calculation return.

Comment: Partition is parallelization unit in Spark. More partitions you've, [theoretically] faster you'll compute your results. IMO fold and aggregate are complementary. The difference is fold must return exactly the same type as input while reduce can transform type and accumulate on this new type.

Answer (score 0):

I think the result you are getting now is as expected, I will try to explain how it works.

```
You have an `rdd` with 10 elements in two partition  
val myrdd1 = sc.parallelize(1 to 10, 2)
```

Lets suppose the two partition contains `p1 = {1,2,3,4,5}` and `p2 = {6,7,8,9,10}`

Now as per the documentation the fold operates in each partition 
Now you get `(default value or zero value which is one in your case) +1+2+3+4+5 = 16` and  `(1 as zero value)+7+8+9+10 = 41`

At last fold those with `(1 as zero value) 16 + 41 = 58`

Similarly, if you have `4` partition `fold` operates in four partitions with default value as `1` and combines the four result with another `fold` with `1` default value and results as `60`.

> Aggregate the elements of each partition, and then the results for all
>   the partitions, using a given associative function and a neutral "zero
>   value". The function op(t1, t2) is allowed to modify t1 and return it
>   as its result value to avoid object allocation; however, it should not
>   modify t2.
>
> This behaves somewhat differently from fold operations implemented for
>   non-distributed collections in functional languages like Scala. This
>   fold operation may be applied to partitions individually, and then
>   fold those results into the final result, rather than apply the fold
>   to each element sequentially in some defined ordering. For functions
>   that are not commutative, the result may differ from that of a fold
>   applied to a non-distributed collection.

For sum zero value should be `0` which gives you the correct result as `55`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your such detail reply, I got your point. I just do not understand why Spark create such kind of calculation. For my understanding, partition is RDD of Spark, it should be belong to Spark env. but now we got different return due to environment.